# how to hide 'view properties'?  (want to allow a user to submit a file but not be able to tell who submitted files)

Tags: permissions, wss-3.0

I'm creating a basic SP site where users can upload documents to a library and view other docs in that library, but not have any way of telling who uploaded what document.

I've got the permissions set up properly, modified views, but there's just one issue - a user can click "View Properties" on a document, and it will show who created and last modified the file.

Any idea how to prevent a user from getting to "View Properties"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

James' solution is a perfectly valid 'no code' option, however if you want to just hide the name of the users who upload and edit the documents while still allowing document properties to be available, you can run a piece of code against the document library. For example

```
       using(SPSite s = new SPSite("http://siteurlhere"))
       {
           using(SPWeb w = s.OpenWeb())
           {

               SPList lib = w.Lists["document library name"];

               lib.ShowUser = false;
               lib.Update();

           }
       }
```

This will cause the created by and modified by fields to be displayed as * * * instead of the actual user name.

Comment: Didn't know this, nice 1. The Object Model is so big though :-S

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view which doesn't display the Link With Menu field, and set this as the default view.